# Como postar código sem que ele seja executado?

Tags: suporte, formatação

Toda vez que posto um código HTML aqui ele executa o código, não mostra o código, como eu posto sem que que ele execute, sei que a pergunta provavelmente é obvia, mas...

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou com os 4 espaços. ;)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help